# How to display ToolTip for AdvanceDatagridColumn in Flex

Tags: user-interface, apache-flex, datagrid

I want to display ToolTip for AdvanceDataGridColumn. The headerText is set as 'ABBR' and ToolTip should be 'internalName'. I am creating columns dynamically as below. Can anyone tell me how I can acheive this.

```
var paxCountNames:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
paxCountNames.dataField = obj['classOfSvcId']+obj['internalName'];
paxCountNames.headerText = obj['abbr'];
paxCountNames.dataTipField = obj['internalName'];
paxCountNames.width = 40;
paxCountNames.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(ADGTextInputRenderer);
passengerCount.children.push(paxCountNames);
```

Comment: Could you provide the structure of the data list(ArrayList) that is used as dataProvider of the AdvancedDataGrid? And the information what data is in the obj would be also helpful.

Comment: ArrayCollection contains obj[abbr], obj[internalName], obj[classofSvcId]

Comment: my problem is not with dataProvider. Row data is coming correctly,... my problem is to display column header tool tip. The columns are creating dynamically through script as above. So I want to know how define a dataTipFunction for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `paxCountNames.dataTipFunction` instead of `paxCountNames.dataTipField`.

```
paxCountNames.dataTipFunction = dTFunction;
function buildToolTip( item:Object ):String {
    return item.someProperty;   // some property you need
}
```

But is necessary to specify `paxCountNames.showDataTips = true` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have successfully created columns dynamically, the only thing you need to do is setting 'showDataTips' property of each column to true to show tooltips.

Example:

`paxCountNames.showDataTips = true;`

Comment: This is not working and my actual requirement is different. I want to display obj[internalName] as tool tip and obj[abbr] as header text. But in this case I am getting tool tip and header text as obj[abbr], I think flex will take header text as tool tip by default. So I need  to know how to customize it.. 
Please help on this.